# Integration of the Drools WorkBench (drools-wb) with an existing Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

I have a Spring Boot application to load/execute rules from an Oracle Database. I would like include the Drools WorkBench User Interface in the same application to allow users to manage (add/edit) the rules.

I've done a lot of searching online and come across articles like [this](https://github.com/bhochhi/drools-guide/wiki/Drools-Workbench) and [this](http://blog.athico.com/2014/04/deploying-kie-drools-wb-on-tomcat.html) that talk about downloading WAR's (i.e. kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-tomcat7.war) and installing it on a standalone Tomcat server.

Since my application is using an embedded Tomcat Server and i'm using Maven/Nexus for dependency management, how can i build/configure and deploy the UI components of the Drools WorkBench within my Spring Boot application without having to manually download WAR's?

Comment: Hi. I have the similar need to do such an integration. Have you got any clue?

Comment: I wasn't able to integrate the Drools Workbench into my existing Spring Boot  application and ended up deploying the WorkBench on a standalone instance of a Tomcat Server. The KIE WorkBench  was very difficult to use for building out rules and we ended up ditching it in the end.

Comment: Are there any document on how to set up everything from scratch, I am pretty new to this but I want to implement the same i.e. loading drl from DB and display it on the workbench